# My 301 Redirect in htaccess didn't redirect correctly

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-404

I want redirect **viewforum.php?id=10** to root of my website but I have error 404, i have test this redirects :

```
RewriteRule ^viewforum.php?id=(\d+)$ / [R=301]
RewriteRule ^/viewforum.php?id=(\d+)$ / [R=301]
RewriteRule ^/viewforum.php?id=10$ / [R=301]
RewriteRule ^viewforum.php?id=10$ / [R=301]
```

But this code doesn't worked.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)id=([0-9]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^viewforum\.php$ /? [R=301,L,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

Is 'viewforum' at beggining of the url ? If not You should not use the `^` character as it points at beggining of URL.

Answer (score 0):

`RewriteRule ^viewforum.php /? [R=301]` should do what you required

Comment: @TrAsHeR Looking for a different answer?

Comment: This will cause redirect `http://domaion.com/viewforum.php` to `http://domaion.com/` not sure if OP wants it.